# Can a session shared between API and message queue worker

Tags: node.js, session, microservices, openid-connect, message-queue

This could seem like a very naive question but don't have much experience in micro-services. My question is if we can share the session between a `message queue worker` and an `API`?

**Why?**

Need to implement an `openID Connect authentication` which will triggered by our worker but after authentication, authorization server returns the token set to our `callback API end-point`(registered in the authentication process) and this end-point require some params(used to start the auth flow including `nonce`, `state` and `code_validation`) to fetch the tokens.

This set of variables should be same in both worker and API end-point.

If it is not possible and there is another way to achieve this. Please share the solution and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a session be shared between API and message queue worker

Yes, it can.

If the implementation of the API and message queue workers are in the same process, then they can share the same session store in process and can thus use the same sessions.

If those two are in different processes, then you will need to store the session data/key in a database that can be accessed from multiple processes and then implement the session handling in both processes to use that common data store.

Comment: What if we want to share these values between multiple service or workers running on separate instances? By using some DB? But using DB for these values would be just overkill. Is there any solution or service available to persist this small data in no session way?

Comment: I think this might help me here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/connect-firestore

Comment: @AdnanAli - Express-session (if you're using Express) supports various databases for it's session store such as redis, mongodb, mysql, etc...  If you store the session in a multi-user database (using one of these session DB connectors), then you can share the session across processes or workers.

Comment: I am using fastify, I assume this can be used with fastify as well as fasity sessions use this plugin(https://github.com/fastify/session) which cas use this as store.

Comment: But  is it a good idea to choose a separate DB like firestore(not as a session Store but as a DB) because in a separate  DB we use it in some lambda function as well.

Comment: @AdnanAli - The point here is that if you want to share a session with more than one process, the session store has to be in some data store that can be accessed from each process that wants to share the session.  That data store can be anything that your environment supports, that your session management supports that has multi-process access.